# Start with multi-site feature now or later?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I have a single installation of Wordpress in my web host and would like it to manage 2 domains or websites. One is for the domain and the other is for its subdomain/s.

dummy example: www.swimming.com and videos.swimming.com

In my limited knowledge, is this where you use the multi-site feature of WordPress?

Another question, is it possible to add that feature later on? I mean, I would have to concentrate first on the main domain and when time comes, I'd focus on the subdomain. So I'm planning to use WordPress without multi-site first and when I'll add a subdomain, that's when I'll switch or add multi-site.

Or do I have to start with multi-site now?

Answer (score 1):

Start right now with multi-site, *before* you add content. Moving content from a former single site to multi-site on the same domain is not exactly a seamless process.

And yes, subdomains are one of the features of a multi-site setup.